# How start annotationProcessing (kapt) for local library?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, annotation-processing

I write small library for annotation processing. Compile it to jar file with Gradle and add to android project. In build.gradle app lvl i added:

```
dependencies {

  //...
    compile files('/Users/I/Documents/Projects/my/test2/build/libs/codelib-0.3.jar')
}
```

and

```
android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true
```

But if i build the project java classes not genered. In another java project (not android!) all perfect works (for build i use command `gradle assemble`) and files creates.
For annotationProcessing in another dependencies (dagger, glide) i use 'kotlin-kapt' and he works fine for there, but he not local obviously.

Comment: Try adding `kapt files('...')` to your `dependencies { ... }` block, kapt uses a separate configuration for its annotation processors.

Comment: oh! I'ts works! But generate in bad folder) But in worked! Thx! Please make it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kapt uses a separate configuration for its annotation processors, namely `kapt`. You need to add your JAR to that configuration as well:

```
dependencies {
     // ...

     kapt files('/Users/I/Documents/Projects/my/test2/build/libs/codelib-0.3.jar')
}
```