# AppDatabase_Impl does not exist by locally adding .jar files Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

Getting issue while i add the .jar files and locally syncing the dependencies. If anyone had faced issue with the same then please comment for the same

Added kotlin-kapt plugin in the app build in top
Added .jar as library by using kapt for room compiler.jar

Attaching image for the reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoC5p.png)

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from adding the dependencies in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: there is a library of room compiler(its used with annotation processor) kapt gives the error i think kapt is not working with .jar files.
Followed this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592662/how-start-annotationprocessing-kapt-for-local-library
but its not helping